# Using Network Share As Visual Studio 2015 Git Remote

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I feel like I'm missing something because this need should be a very common one...

Assume this scenario:

- Five developers, each running Windows 10 workstations with Visual Studio 2015.
- One networked Windows 2012 Server file server.

The Windows Server is available to all five developers using a UNC path that includes the IP Address (such as "\1.2.3.4\C$\repo\temp").

All I want to do is place a Visual Studio solution on the file server in the target path \1.2.3.4\C$\repo\temp. Once the solution is there, I want each developer to clone from it and develop using a local repo before pushing changes back to the file server.

Here are my questions:

1. In this case, isn't the file server technically a "remote repo" with respect to the five developer workstations?
2. If that answer to (1) is Yes then it seems that remote repos in Visual Studio must be defined as https:// targets (UNC paths don't work). Can a remote repo be defined as a UNC path on the network?

Perhaps the term "remote repo" is very specific in Git parlance...such that a remote Git repo must be either a third-party repo, such as GitHub, or some other internet-based endpoint. But that just doesn't seem right. I don't understand why the remote repo can't just be a file path on the local workstation or on any other available path on the local network.

Perhaps the file server in my example isn't technically a "remote repo"; it's okay with me if it actually is a "local repo" on the network--if that's the case, I'll learn to refer to it as a local repo... Ultimately, all I care about is that the file server will hold the team's "master" branch, and will be used to create builds. All developers will make pushes back to the file server repo.

How can I set up such a networked file server and use it as my team's master repo? If you don't know the Visual Studio 2015 way of achieving this then I would still accept answers that explain how this would be done using the Git command-line tools...

Comment: Have you considered running a local gitlab server?  (https://about.gitlab.com/)

Comment: No, I don't have any need for server software. I only want the network share to be treated as the master branch.

Comment: the repo syntax would be `file:///path/to/repo.git/` but I'm not sure how that would work with unc paths.  Perhaps you could mount the unc path as a drive letter (or in a folder on the local drive..)? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS)

Comment: ps: treating a network mounted path as a local file system will usually lead to file-locking issues sooner or later (hence the gitlab suggestion).

Comment: No, I tried the file:/// option and it doesn't see the endpoint. I tried mapping a drive letter, didn't work.

Comment: well it would be more `/`s:  the protocol is `file://` (similarly to http://), then the first `/` is for the root of the folder hierarchy, so perhaps `file:////unc/path/repo.git/` ?

Comment: Well, the file reference didn't work. BUT, I had a thought, which DID work. I used the UNC path \\1.2.3.4\C$\x\y, but instead of pointing to the root folder, I terminated it with .git, so the path looked like \\1.2.3.4\C$\x\y\.git. If you have VS 2015, let me know and I'll provide more details. Meanwhile, I'd like to give you credit for this so if you want to create an answer that suggests using a UNC that ends with .git, I'll accept it! Visual Studio creates a hidden .git folder when you add a create a repo, so it's not like some other conventions that have a filename with a .git extension...

Comment: did some research on what the .git extension is for and put it in my answer..

Comment: I did such a thing to introduce a team to git but I don't think that's a good durable solution because perfs are really bad compare to a repository shared through http or git protocol. Prefer gogs.io, gitlab, scm manager, git deamon or everything else instead!

Comment: Gotcha--that's good feedback. We may need to configure an http/https endpoint on the server in question in order to be able to use http rather than UNC references. Performance has been quite bad using UNC. We are trying to avoid using any server software but Gitlab keeps popping up so we may evaluate. We also have access to a TFS license, and I understand that TFS backs all Git repos to SQL Server. Might also be worth looking into...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a central repository (that will be shared with other users), you should create it with the `--bare` option:

```
git init --bare myrepo.git
```

this implies that there is no working directory created, and there is no top-level `.git` directory (instead the contents that would "normally" be in the .git folder will be at the top level).

A bare repository requires the users to use the clone/pull/fetch/push commands to interact with the repository (as opposed to add/commit which interacts with local repositories).

The convention is to name bare repositories with a `.git` extension. While git itself doesn't care, much of the tooling expects it.

So, if you create a bare repo on a UNC path you should be able to use it directly

\1.2.3.4\C$\x\y.git

I would probably share the directory explicitly on the server so you get a nicer looking path...

Comment: Ideally, I would like to see a solution that does not involve a git command-line interface and sticks to the VS 2015 IDE, but this suffices and also explains the .git extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I've done this in the past we used unix-style UNC paths: ie: `//SERVERNAME/Share/repository.git` and ensure the shared repository is a bare repository (ie: `git init --bare repository.git`). Adding `.git` to a repository directory name is just a common convention to indicate it is a bare repository.

Example with a non-bare remote share (git version 2.7.0.windows.1):

```
C:\Code>git ls-remote \\SERVER\c$\Code\Build
fatal: '\SERVER\c$\Code\Build' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

C:\Code>git ls-remote //SERVER/c$/Code/Build
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        HEAD
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        refs/heads/master
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Given the response on the first attempt it's clear we have a quoting problem so doubling the backslashes can solve it -- or switch to forward slashes. You can use a file:// URL scheme, but you still need two slashes to indicate the UNC server part so:

```
C:\Code>git ls-remote file:////SERVER/c$/Code/Build
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        HEAD
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        refs/heads/master
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ad081d35144157551e3728d6deadf19ae106ced0        refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: So what would the steps be from Visual Studio? Say you have a bare git folder. Then what's next? You can't pull from it. Also, I don't know how to do an initial "push" if the solution isn't already under source control within Visual Studio. Usually, you add source control to an existing solution and that creates a .git folder in that solution's folder structure. I can experiment with pushing to an empty repo but as of now I'm unsure how...