# remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking

Tags: windows, git, networking

Im working on window environnement and I have a remote git repository on the network.
Created using

```
git init --bare
```

Then I clone the project on my local, I can work on it commit and push.
But at a moment, i could'nt push anymore with the following error:

```
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 1.93 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object directory /SERVER/Apps/myApp.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To //SERVER/Apps/myApp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '//SERVER/Apps/myApp.git'
```

So I tried to create another repo and same happend...

do you have any clue about how this error happened and how to fix it ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
user.name=Flim
user.email=flim@myMail.com
alias.tree=log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=//SERVER/Apps/myApp.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: /SERVER/Apps/myApp.git/objects should be /SERVER/Apps/myApp/.git/objects, shouldn't it? perhaps a config or path mis-configured somewhere?

Comment: i'm curious what the output of "git config -l" is

Comment: The path /SERVER/Apps/myApp.git/objects is correct and exist, but i wonder is it miss one slash at the path start ?

Comment: I believe your suspicion is correct: Git is assuming that `//a/b/c` and `/a/b/c` mean the same thing, so it simplifies away the extra `/`. But on your OS, that extra `/` is not actually *extra*. POSIX leaves the behavior of multiple leading slashes to the underlying OS, and most Unix/Linux systems discard extra slashes, but Windows may use it to mean "traverse outside the root file system to a super-root from which network drives are available". If Git assumes Linux behavior, you must use some other syntax, so that Git won't simplify away a necessary character.

Comment: Thanks. I succeed to push my commit before so i guess its not the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So close! This will be fixed in the upcoming Git 2.12 (Q1 2017).
See "[Git push fail to a Windows share](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368730/6309)"

> `normalize_path_copy()` is not prepared to keep the double-slash of a
>   `//server/share/dir` kind of path, but treats it like a regular POSIX
>   style path and transforms it to `/server/share/dir`.

So it works the first time, then the wrong path gets registered and then, it does not work anymore.

As a workaround for now, see if you can not map that shared path to a drive letter.

```
net use z: \\SERVER\Apps
```

See "[Map network drive command line](https://www.windows-commandline.com/map-network-drive-command-line/)".
Then use that path as your remote `origin` url.

```
cd C:\path\to\my\local\repo
git remote set-url origin Z:\myApp.git
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is clear & simple. And the workaround works perfectly.

Comment: can you also just prefix the path with `file:`? eg `file://server/shar/dir`?

Comment: @Souleste Yes, both syntax can work. `file:////server/shared/dir`, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934226/6309) for instance, as explained in the [local protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934226/6309).